# Send a mouse left click to a sopcast mute button, in c#

Tags: c#

I’m trying to send a mouse left click to a sopcast mute button, in c#, but with no result.
Here is what I did:

```
  const int BN_CLICKED = 245;  
public static void mute_sopcast() 
{ 

    IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("#32770", null); 
    IntPtr chwnd1 = FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "AfxOleControl70su", null); 
    IntPtr chwnd2 = FindWindowEx(chwnd1, IntPtr.Zero, "#32770", null); 
    IntPtr chwnd3 = FindWindowEx(chwnd2, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Mute"); 

    PostMessage(chwnd3, BN_CLICKED, 0, (int)IntPtr.Zero); 

    //The code bellow I made it to see if chwnd… is zero or not.

    if (chwnd3 == new IntPtr(0)) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("IntPtr(0)"); 
    } 
    else if (chwnd3 == IntPtr.Zero) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("IntPtr.Zero"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("IntPtr.Zero not empty"); 
    } 


}
```

Winspector Spy gives me this:

```
000E036E: #32770 
    …
    00070406: AfxOleControl70su
        002C06A2: #32770
            …
            000F03A4: Button “Mute”
```

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using System;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace automouse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
        public const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendMessage(button2.Handle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            SendMessage(button2.Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button2 clicked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
SendMessage(chwnd4, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
SendMessage(chwnd4, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Also this example it doesn’t work for me. 
The problem is that I can’t find a way to take the handle for this button. 
Can someone tell me how to do this in this situation?

Comment: Chwnd3 being zero is bad. Maybe you should check hwnd and the others are not zero as well. Then use EnumChildWindows on the last one that is non-zero to see why you can't find it by class and Name

Answer (score 1):

[BN_CLICKED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not a window message - it is a notification code send as part of the `WPARAM` of a WM_COMMAND message.  The WM_COMMAND message requires the control ID as well which isn't available externally.   Also WM_COMMAND message are send to the parent window the control, not to the control itself.

The correct way to send this would be:

```
const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
const int BN_CLICKED = 245; 

int controlID = ??; // Something you don't know
int wParam = BN_CLICKED >> 16 | controlID;

PostMessage(chwnd3, WM_COMMAND, wParam , (int)chwnd4);
```

Of course this assumes that the code is using WM_COMMAND messages and not directly listening for button up/down messages.

A better bet would be to set focus to the button and then send a spacebar press to using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) to perform the button click.

Comment: Yup.  Add to it that BN_CLICKED is sent (not posted) to the owner of the button.  Fix it all with BM_CLICK.

Comment: I changed my code into this but with no result:

const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111; 
const int BN_CLICKED = 245;  
 
int controlID = 10006; // I took this value from the properties window in the Winspector Spy of the 000F03A4: Button “Mute” from the ID row.
int wParam = BN_CLICKED >> 16 | controlID; 
 
PostMessage(chwnd3, WM_COMMAND, wParam , (int)chwnd4);

Comment: I think the problem is in this line “IntPtr chwnd4 = FindWindowEx(chwnd3, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Mute");” because I get the message "IntPtr(0)". In my opinion I should have the message "IntPtr not empty"